# How to read application setting of Azure App service in ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0, azure-appservice

I am working on a .NET Core 6.0 "Hello World" app and it'll be deployed as an Azure web service.

I am trying to read value from Azure App Service -> Configuration -> ApplicationSetting -> mykey, but I am not able to access value of `mykey` after deploying to app service. I am able to read value of `mykey` in local while debugging.

[image]

Project type:

[image: This is my]

I have to read `mykey` in `Program.cs`. What is the simplest way to read the value of `mykey` since it is just a hello world app?

`Program.cs`:

```
using HelloWorldApi.Helpers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Certificate;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    
var provider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
var configuration = provider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(o =>
{
    o.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(o =>
    {
    });
}).ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, builder) =>
{
    var settings = builder.Build();

    // I tried different ways but not getting value of mykey. 
    // This code is returning null
    var connectionString = configuration.GetValue<string>("mykey");
});

var app = builder.Build();
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add appsetting.json please

Comment: I am not able to access value of **mykey** after deploying to app service. I am able to read value of mykey in local while debugging.

Comment: In [`appsettings.json`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDs2p.png) file add the settings as  `"AppSettings": {
    "mykey": "test"
  }`

Comment: With your code read it as `var MyAppSettings = configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
 var AppsetVal = MyAppSettings.GetValue<string>("mykey");`

Comment: Provided the solution with your `Appsettings`, please check once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check the below changes in your code to read the values from Azure App Settings.

In `Program.cs`,

***Retrieving values with your code.***

```cs
 var AppsetVal = configuration.GetValue<string>("mykey")
```

***OR***

***From my Sample code***

```cs
var AppsetVal = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("mykey");
```

***My `appsettings.json` file:***

```cs
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*", 
  "mykey": "test"
}
```

***Settings in Azure:***
[image]

Here Iam displaying the value in API Controller.

***In WeatherForecastController .cs:***

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication7.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {      
        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;
        private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            //var MyAppSettings = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");

            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {              
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)],
                myval = Configuration.GetSection("mykey").Value

            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

In `WeatherForecast.cs`, add

```cs
 public string? myval { get; set; }
```

***Deployed App Service Output:***

[image]

Comment: i am not getting Configuration  in builder.Configuration

Comment: How you are checking the deployed appsetting value in `Program.cs` file? Are you doing remote debugging?

Comment: no not doing remotedebugging, where are you using MyAppSettings in controller method? what is dot net core version of your project

Comment: You will get the value from Azure appsettings only for the deployed app.You can only check the value by displaying or remote debugging.

Comment: Iam using .NET Core 6.

Comment: Ignore `var MyAppSettings = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");`.I have set value in [myval](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49H18.png).

Comment: Tried in multiple ways. Gave you the trial code as well. Updated the Answer. Please check now.